# How to configure RAID-5 for OS root (Ubuntu Server 18.04)

Tags: ubuntu, software-raid, mdadm, ovh

I have a fresh dedicated server I have provisioned running Ubuntu Server 18.04 and with 3x480GB SSDs (no hardware RAID controller though). The UI of the hosting provider will not allow the “/boot” or “/“ partitions to be configured with RAID-5 at provisioning (it forces both to be provisioned as RAID-1). It will however let me freely set up other partitions with RAID-5 at other mount points (i.e. it will let me set up a RAID-5 partition mounted at “/home”). I am wondering if/how I can work within these constraints (working within the OS presumably, moving things around and re-partitioning after provisioning, though there is also IPMI if that is somehow necessary) to eventually get “/“ onto a RAID-5 partition.